# UILabel appearance setTextColor doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uisearchbar, textcolor

I'm trying to set the color of placeholder's text in `UISearchBar` and I've placed `[[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];` into my AppDelegate's method `(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` but it doesn't work.

After that I've placed it into view controller's method where I create `UISearchBar` programmatically and it helps me but there's another problem: I'm creating search bars in a several view controllers and the text color of placeholder changed only for one. Actually for that who did load first and the rest of search bar placeholder's text color are still has no changes.

Can anyone explain how to change it for all search bars in project?

Comment: Create an abstract ViewController with this "setup" and reuse it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Tested works fine.

```
[searchBar setValue:[UIColor redColor] forKeyPath:@"_searchField._placeholderLabel.textColor"];
```